# How to use "import" in a polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm trying something like the following:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <template> <div>{{data.name}}</div> </template>

    <script>
        import data from 'data';

        class MyApp {
            constructor() { ... }
            beforeRegister() {
                this.is = 'my-app';
                this.properties = {
                    data: {
                        type: Object,
                        value: function () {
                            return data;
                        },
                    }
                };
            }

            ready() {}
            ...
        }  
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

So, I have here ES6 too, so I constructed the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/**/*.{js,html}'])
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.if('*.html', $.crisper())) // Extract JS from .html files
        .pipe($.if('*.js', $.babel()))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
    });
});
```

This works as long as I don't have the `import data from 'data'` line. Now I get the following error in the browser:

```
require is not defined
```

So, I decided to add `browserify` to the process just below `babel`

```
 .pipe($.if('*.js', $.browserify({ debug: true, extensions: ['.js', '.html'] })))
```

Now I get a transpile error

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I think I'm close, but I'm now stuck here unfortunately. To reproduce this I've created a github repo [here](https://github.com/ajs2/polymer-es6)

You can check it out and do:

```
$> cd polymer-es6
$> npm install
$> bower install
$> gulp js
```

A bonus question: Why is the `constructor` not called ? It seems that `ready` is called instead.

Comment: What's the filename of that first file? I think you're going to have problems trying to compile files like that that mix markup and JS with Babel unless you blacklist the JSX transformer (`react`). If you're going to use browserify you should probably use the `babelify` transform instead of a gulp plugin.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Any suggestions how to do this in the current situation with crisper ?

Comment: Check out IMD (Imports Module Loader). That might help. https://github.com/polymerlabs/imd. I specifically didn't talk about `import` because more experimenting needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I think for now I'll rewrite my import into an other polymer element. For now I've an other polymer topic to explore :)